# Revenge: what can we do?

Tags: support, flags, serial-voting

20 minutes ago, in a matter of minutes I got downvotes on 6 of my past answers. My guess is that it comes from somebody seeking revenge because I downvoted one of his/her answers.

I don't know if I should find it sad or funny, but anyway I have two concerns with this. The first one is that some of my good answers don't look so good now with one less upvote. The second is that I don't really want people like this in our community.

Does stackoverflow have policies in place to address such behaviors?

[Edit] my question was marked as duplicate, however the other answers don't explain what happens to the downvoter. btw once again I am impressed by stackoverflow's ability to moderate a community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  If you were serially downvoted, the system will detect it and remove the downvotes.  The downvoter, as a result, may lose some priviledges afforded to him prior to the violation.

Comment: I believe if a post gets deleted for spam -- the poster loses rep, not sure about serial voting though. I've seen suspensions (rep set @ 1), but afaik, they don't actually lose reputation.

Comment: Just for clarity; votes are invalidated, and reputations reset appropriately, which could affect privileges. If a suspension results, all privileges are revoked during the suspension. After that, privileges are restored to their appropriate levels based on the legitimate reputation score.